# Running complex tasks in background with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, background, background-service

I am working on an application that collects Wifi, Bluetooth, and Sensor data such as the accelerometer. The application collects and processes the data a little bit and then sends it to the backend, and the backend will return the guessed location. I have done these operations and working properly while the application is in foreground mode. But I need the application to do these in the background and foreground both. I watched some tutorials about background service but many of them souts the "hello world" from background and my problem is far more complex than that.

I had created different repositories for each different task in Dart language:
[image]

All of the repositories are doing the things related to their names, and then I merged their functionalities in "inclusive_component" then I call a method like this `InclusiveComponent.instance.start()` in Flutter's UI codes.

All functionalities provided by `InclusiveComponent.instance.start()` must have run in the background too. How can I achieve that, is there any roadmap? Is there any basic implementation like `background(InclusiveComponent.instance.start())` or do I have to rewrite all the repository codes to be runnable in the background etc? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried using Flutter isolate?

Comment: I'll check it out, I thought it was for multithreading only